# React Native: minHeight in percent is not working correctly like in Web

Tags: react-native, react-native-flexbox

Below are my experimental result. Does those seems right?

minHeight in percent is not working correctly like in Web, is there any workaround about it?

#--- **flexDirection = column**; React Native Version = 0.68.4 ;

minHeight always cross height and maxHeight.

minWidth always cross width and maxWidth.

flex will not cross maxHeight.

alignSelf=stretch will not cross width.

flex/%height/%maxHeight only be used if **height** keyword present in container.

alignSelf=stretch/%minWidth/%width/%maxWidth only be used if **width** keyword present in container.

for primary axis(here column) **%minHeight** is not working correctly. need to use **number** value only.

for secondary axis (here row) all /%minWidth/%width/%maxWidth works.

---#

**Thanks in advance.**

N.B: Sample code

```
// I applied on every elements below styles
// margin: 0,
// padding: 0,
// borderWidth: 0,
// borderRadius: 0,
// left: 0,
// top: 0,
// backgroundColor: 'transparent',
// overflow: 'hidden',

<>
  <View
    style={{
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }}
    onLayout={(e) => {
      console.log('Main: ', e.nativeEvent.layout);
    }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        //see image 1
        
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 150,
        width: '50%',
        maxWidth: 120,
        minHeight: 120,
        height: '50%',
        maxHeight: 192,
        backgroundColor: 'green',

        //removed previous code and changed to below. see image 2

        // flex: 1,
        minWidth: 150,
        width: '50%',
        maxWidth: 120,
        // minHeight: 120,
        minHeight: '40%',
        height: '50%',
        // maxHeight: 192,
        backgroundColor: 'green',

      }}
      onLayout={(e) => {
        console.log('AfterMain: ', e.nativeEvent.layout);
      }}
    >
    </View>
  </View>
</>
```

[image 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sfpso8bOoLLVIYOM83H7BFYiV6RXrX3U/view?usp=sharing)

[image 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fSZxccO6C1G-qmtbqIvliC_cN9N6mM77/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: please add a code tag it will be more accessible to index and easier to provide solutions for another user.

Comment: @CADENTIC, I added some code and images.